# What is the value of $a$ in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am new to this forum. And hoping to get some answers on some mathematical equations. Here is my first one -

$$(x - 5) (a + x) = x^2 - 25$$

What is the value of $a$ in this equation?

EDIT: This question is actually a multiple choice question from our BCS exam in the early 90's. And it actually had 4 options to answer as followed:

1) 5

2) -5

3) 25

4) -25

I also believe that the expression has a mistake and I actually cannot figure out the real problem. That's why I posted here, if anyone can figure that out.  Hope this helps to all of you.

Please help me out. TIA.

Imran

Second edit: I have fixed the expression with correct equation value (replacing a with x). And also I have solved the math. Thanks for the all the suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to solve this equation for $x$: $$0=x^2+5x-ax-a^2-5a-25$$?

Comment: and $a$ is the given parameter

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is not clear. The equation has two variables, $a$ and $x$, so there is no "value of $a$". Perhaps you want to know $a$ in terms of $x$, or the opposite. Please [edit] the question to tell us just what you are asking, and show us what you tried and where you are stuck. (Don't put that in a comment - [edit] the question.)

Comment: Do you require $x,a$ to be integers?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the edits that you made.

Answer (score 1):

To solve for a in the equation
$$(a - 5)(a + x) = x^2 - 25$$
expand the product, bring everything to the left side
and rewrite it as a quadradic equation in a.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple question. Do you know what the difference of squares is? Here's what it looks like:

$$
(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2
$$

$25$ is $5^2$ and $a+x$ is the same thing as $x+a$ by something called the commutative property of addition:

$$
(x - 5) (a + x) = x^2 - 25\Longleftrightarrow
(x - 5) (x+a) = x^2 - 5^2
$$

It's quite clear from the above that $a$ should be $5$. So, the correct answer is $1)$.